# How to return the values in a junction as an array?

Tags: arrays, raku, junction

Define a junction `my $j = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5`, now I want to get an array of its value `[1 2 3 4 5]`, how should I implement this?

I tried `$j.values` but Perl6 gave me the whole junction as an element: `[any((1), (2), (3), (4), (5))]`.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction): *"Junctions are meant to be used as matchers in boolean context; introspection of junctions is not supported. If you feel the urge to introspect a junction, use a Set or a related type instead."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Håkon Hægland already pointed out, this is not something you're supposed to do:

> Junctions are meant to be used as matchers in boolean context; introspection of junctions is not supported. If you feel the urge to introspect a junction, use a Set or a related type instead.
>
> -- [docs.perl6.org/type/Junction](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction)

However, it is possible.

First, you can use authothreading (ie the automatic evaluation of each branch of a junction when passed to a function that expects an argument of type `Any`):

```
sub unjunc(Junction $j) {
    gather -> Any $_ { .take }.($j);
}
```

Second, you can poke into the guts and manually extract the values:

```
sub unjunc(Junction $j) {
    multi extract(Any $_) { .take }
    multi extract(Junction $_) {
        use nqp;
        my $list := nqp::getattr($_, Junction, '$!storage');
        my int $elems = nqp::elems($list);
        loop (my int $i = 0; $i < $elems; $i = $i + 1) {
            extract nqp::atpos($list, $i);
        }
    }
    gather extract $j;
}
```

If your junction is non-recursive (ie does not contain other junctions you want to flatten), the latter approach can be simplified:

```
my $j := 1|2|3;
say nqp::p6bindattrinvres(nqp::create(List), List, '$!reified',
    nqp::getattr($j, Junction, '$!storage'));
```

Comment: The nqp variants are broken. In order to build the list without depending on Rakudo's implementation details directly, you need to thread.

Answer (score 10):

This is intentional, as far as I know.

Imagine $j containing a Junction of hashes: then $j.values would be a junction of Seq's, *not* the hashes themselves.

If you want the array of a junction, then maybe you should start from an array, and build a junction out of that:

```
my @a = 1,2,3,4,5;
my $j = any(@a);
```

If you *really* want to go the Junction -> Array way, you could, but it would involve using nqp, and that's something I would not recommend in userland code.

Comment: This can be simplified even further:

`my $j = any my @a = 1,2,3,4,5;`

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to thread a junction of `Mu` so as to build an `Array` of eigenstates with their containers preserved. Because `Mu` is a supertype of the `Any` that autothreading is oriented towards, we can't depend on that feature while covering all possible eigenstate types, however.

`Mu.ACCEPTS` has a `multi method ACCEPTS(Mu:U: Junction:D) is default` candidate to allow for smartmatches of junctions against any type object. This allow for a manual threading if fed a thunk that can recurse over `ACCEPTS` to be chained with `CALL-ME`, which can thread over its invocant:

```
class Unison is Mu is repr<Uninstantiable> {
    method CALL-ME(Mu $topic is raw --> Array:D) {
        my @list;
        proto sub push(Mu) {*}
        multi sub push(Mu $topic is raw) { @list.BIND-POS(@list.elems, $topic) }
        multi sub push(Junction:D $junction) { self.ACCEPTS($junction).(&push) }
        self.ACCEPTS($topic).(&push);
        @list
    }

    multi method ACCEPTS(Mu $topic is raw) {
        -> &accept { accept $topic }
    }
}

say Unison(1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5);    # OUTPUT: [1 2 3 4 5]
say Unison((1 | (2, 3) & 4) ^ 5); # OUTPUT: [1 (2 3) 4 5]
```

`ACCEPTS` must not be overridden in its entirety, but since `Mu` is the parent and not `Any`, just the one `Mu` candidate can cover its bases. This will only work on a type object invocant, so this is given the `Uninstantiable` REPR.